# Coerce a function into an expression?

Tags: r

Is there any function or method that coerces a function object into an expression in R?

Suppose I have `u = function (x, y) 2 * x^0.8 * y^0.2`. What I would like to achieve is convert `u` into a `call` or `expression` object. Example, `2 * x^0.8 * y^0.2` with `mode(.) == 'call'` or `expression(2 * x^0.8 * y^0.2)`

I know that you can do something like:

```r
str2lang(deparse(u)[[2]])
2 * x^0.8 * y^0.2
```

`deparse` can still be made to work for cases when functions have several lines.

```r
ff = function(x, y) {
        x = x + 1
        y = y + 1
        return(x+y) 
        }

str2lang(paste(deparse(ff)[-1], collapse='\n'))

{
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
    return(x + y)
}
```

Is there a better way already implemented in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `body`.  No packages are used.

```
b <- body(ff)

# test
eval(b, list(x = 3, y = 10))
## [1] 15

# compare to ff
ff(x = 3, y = 10)
## [1] 15
```

Comment: Exactly, that is perfect.  `body` was hiding right under my nose. Thank you.